# Can I figure out if a user who downloaded my program actually installed it?

Tags: php, cookies

I made some software which is free to download in hopes that it picks up. I am paying several affiliates when they send me traffic, and the way it works right now is that I give each affiliate a unique link, and the affiliates get credited only when my software is actually downloaded. 
However, what would be ideal is if I could track whether the user actually installed the software or not. Is there some way to do this without requiring the user to register the software? (Keep in mind that I need to know which affiliate the user was referred by)

Originally I had thought of creating a cookie on the user's browser with the affiliate's ID, and then when the software installation is complete, it would open up a browser to show a Thank You page, at which point I could read the cookie and figure out which affiliate this user was tied to. However, this doesn't work if the software is downloaded with any browser other than the user's default browser....

Another idea I had was storing the user's IP address in a database, and then matching that up when the Thank You page is opened, but this wouldn't work well when users are part of a large network, such as at a university.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Another idea I had was storing the user's IP address in a database, and then matching that up when the Thank You page is opened, but this wouldn't work well when users are part of a large network, such as at a university.

Send each users' an installer with a personalized name (e.g. binary01, binary02, binary03...). Let the installer read its own name upon download, and put it into the Thank You page as a GET parameter, i.e. `http://www.yoursite.com/thankyou?exe=binary03`.

The binary file on the server is always the same and one file, but the downloader will report a different name for each affiliate (or you can keep several copies of the same binary, but that's more difficult to keep synced).

For example, this could be a download link:

```
<?php
    // Download URL, of the form http://www.yoursite.com/download.php?aff=AffName
    // You can rewrite this with Apache's mod_rewrite and have .../filename-AffName.exe

    $affiliates = array(
        // You can keep these in a database
        "widgets"  => "Widgets'r'us",
        "foobar"   => "Foo's Software Bar",
    );

    $aff  = isset($_GET['aff']) ?  $_GET['aff'] : 'unaffiliated';
    $base = "YourBinary";
    $ext  = '.exe';

    $file = $base.$ext;
    $name = $base.'-'.$aff.$ext;

    Header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($name));
    Header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    Header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    Header("Content-Type: application/download");
    Header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
    Header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));

    readfile($file);
?>
```

As for how to read package name, it will depend on the installer. InnoSetup will export the information as a script variable `{srcexe}`, Advanced Installer will have it as [SETUPEXEDIR], and so on.

You may want to bump this up to a "first install registration" function, though, if it so happens that many users download the installation (e.g. at work, at an Internet café, etc.) and then run it later without Internet connectivity. You might want to store a "InstallationID" registry value to the Affiliate Name upon installation (by reading it from the executable), and then the program might look it up and try exchanging it for a numerical ID or a UUID if it is not.

This way you get the best of both worlds, don't annoy the customer ("Cannot install without an Internet connection! Yeeech!"), and even get a UUID thrown in the bargain.

Comment: I think this is going to be the most effective solution. Only thing to worry about is user changing the name...but that's not very common...is it?

Comment: "Once in a blue moon" seems appropriate :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would venture an educated guess that your idea of using a cookie would be best. It's unlikely that a user would use something other than their default browser to download software, except in the case that they're setting up a new computer and haven't gotten around to installing their browser of choice yet.

You could also distribute different executables that open specific links for each affiliate, if you don't mind changing a string and re-compiling your software for each one.

Comment: I actually see quite a few people who don't change their default browser (ie) and just have a chrome/firefox shortcut on their desktop :/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to silently send HTTP GET request back to your home server upon first execution of your application - basically ping back home, and not to open any browser at all. You can even send unique device ID to be sure that this is new device. You probably want to remember this event in your local database and not to send this every time.

Note that for this to work, you application must have [INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission listed in AndroidManifest.xml.

There is an issue about privacy though: you should make it clear to the user that you ping back home.

Comment: Where does this post say anything about android?

Comment: Hmm, somehow I mentally skipped this. But, pinging back home is universal idea and can be applied for other applications and operating systems as well.

Comment: I actually found some good solutions for mobile applications...but sadly mine is a desktop app. The main problem is linking the user's web session with the downloaded application. I think lserni's answer is the easiest (only?) way to pass information from web to installer